# Overriding init in subclass

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, uiview, initialization, init

In Objective-C, is it necessary to override all inherited constructors of a subclass to add custom initialization logic?

For example, would the following be correct for a `UIView` subclass with custom initialization logic?

```
@implementation CustomUIView

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self initHelper];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)theFrame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:theFrame];
    if (self) {
        [self initHelper];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:decoder];
    if (self) {
        [self initHelper];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) initHelper {
    // Custom initialization
}

@end
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Every Cocoa Touch (and Cocoa) class has a designated initializer; for `UIView`, as stated [in this documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html), that method is `initWithFrame:`. In this particular case, you'll only need to override `initWithFrame`; all other calls will cascade down and hit this method, eventually.

This goes beyond the scope of the question, but if you do end up creating a custom initializer with extra parameters, you should make sure to the designated initializer for the superclass when assigning `self`, like this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)theFrame puzzle:(Puzzle *)thePuzzle title:(NSString *)theTitle {
    self = [super initWithFrame:theFrame];
    if (self) {
        [self setPuzzle:thePuzzle];
        [self setTitle:theTitle];
        [self initHelper];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: So even if I instance CustomUIView with plain init, it will call initWithFrame?

Comment: That's correct. he way to test this would be to override both init: and initWithFrame:, set breakpoints (or NSLog statements) on the first line of each, and instance CustomUIView using init. You should see init get hit first, followed by initWithFrame:.

Comment: What's important to remember is that if an object gets instantiated from a NIB, `initWithCoder:` is called, and **NOT** `initWithFrame:`.

Comment: @Pascal that's a good point and probably should be edited into the answer, from the doc referenced in the answer about `initWithFrame`: _"If you use Interface Builder to design your interface, this method is not called when your view objects are subsequently loaded from the nib file."_

Comment: Additional quote from [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW8) about loading views from resource files: _"Custom views in OS X receive an initWithFrame: message."_, while _"Custom views in iOS do not use the initWithFrame: method for initialization."_

Comment: So with @Pascal comments, Sam's accepted answer is false.  Since you can't rely on a convention for constructors, it's probably less time consuming to assume you must override all of them, to ensure your init is run each time.

Comment: @GregoryJohnson Not necessarily _all_ of them; `initWithCoder:` is special, it's part of the `NSCoding` category. You're fine with overriding the designated initializer, `initWithFrame:` in this case, **PLUS** `initWithCoder:`.

Answer (score 6):

In case of using Interface Builder, the one is called is :

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
       //do sth
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In general you should follow the designated initializer convention.  The designated initializer is the init, that covers the initialization of all instance variables.  The designated initializer is also the method that is called by other init methods of a class.

Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-106376) about designated initializers.

`initWithFrame:` is the designated initializer of the NSView class. Apple's Cocoa documentation always explicitly mentions the designated initializer of a class.

`initWithCoder:` is discussed [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944823/iphone-is-initwithcoder-an-exception-to-the-usual-designated-initializer-desig).